# "set -eo pipefail" not working in Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Windows subsystem for Linux on my Windows 10 machine which is supposed to be emulating Ubuntu 16.04.  When I try to execute a script that has the following 2 lines at the top of the script, it gives me the error `:invalid option name set: pipefail`

Script lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail
```

This script runs fine on my Mac and on a CentOS system I have.  I have checked 
(and verified) my Ubuntu shell to ensure it supports the pipefail option in bash by running `set -o`.

The output of `cat -net /path/to/myscript` is:

```
#!/bin/bash^M$
set -eo pipefail^M$
```

This question was marked as a duplicate of "How to change Windows line-ending to Unix version" but I do not feel it is duplicative of that because I personally did not know that the problem I was having (that is outlined in my question) was being caused by the type of line-ending in my shell script.  The answer in each of the questions is the same but 2 different questions were asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated by the `^M` sequences in your `cat -net` output, you have saved the script with Windows-style (CRLF) line endings rather than Unix-style (LF only)

In fact, we could have guessed that from the truncated error message: the "real" error is that `pipefail\r` is an invalid option name. However, the carriage return causes the cursor to reset to the start of the line and overwrite the preceding characters. Compare

```
$ cat -net bad.sh
     1  #!/bin/bash$
     2  set -eo fhqwhgads$

$ ./bad.sh
./bad.sh: line 2: set: fhqwhgads: invalid option name
```

and

```
$ cat -net bad.sh
     1  #!/bin/bash$
     2  set -eo pipefail^M$

$ ./bad.sh
: invalid option name: pipefail
```