# set: pipefail failing on WSL windows

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, apache2

I cloned this repo on WSL2 https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/dev/breeze/doc/01_installation.rst#docker-in-wsl-2 and tried to build a docker image that uses also this script https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/scripts/docker/install_os_dependencies.sh, but this error appears: ERROR [main 4/34] RUN bash /scripts/docker/install_os_dependencies.sh dev 0.7s
[main 4/34] RUN bash /scripts/docker/install_os_dependencies.sh dev: : invalid option name/install_os_dependencies.sh: line 2: set: pipefail

[pipefail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7sA2.png)

I found from this question [set: pipefail failing on WSL windows 11 ubuntu 22.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497926/set-pipefail-failing-on-wsl-windows-11-ubuntu-22-04-3) that the problem is that the file is not Linux formatted. I thought that WSL is POSIX compliant, but apparently it is not.

I reformatted the file to unix with dos2unix, library suggested in that question, but it still throws this error.

Please help, cause I am stuck. Also, is there any way to do the WSL folders to be POSIX compliant?

Thank you!

Comment: Please verify that your changes with `dos2unix` took effect using `file /scripts/docker/install_os_dependencies.sh`

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, I did, the file is now: scripts/docker/install_os_dependencies.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, while before it was Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators. So dos2unix removed that problematic CRLF terminators, but the script still does not work. Any more ideas?

Comment: Sorry - I can't think of anything else that would cause the exact symptom where the error description `invalid option name` gets moved to the start of the message and overwrites the filename like that